# Trying to update integer in database by using increment function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, controller

I want to add `1` to my previous `karma` value in my database.
Here's what I am doing in my controller:-

```
 public function response(Request $request, $id)
    {   
        $globalPost = PublicAnswer::find($id);

        if($request->resp == "normal")
        {
          $answered_by = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $globalPost->answered_by)
        ->increment('karma', +1);
        
        }
}
```

**Here's my database:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('karma')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

If I replace `increment` function with `update` this is the error that I am getting:-

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::update() must be of the type array, string given,

I cannot see any errors and the karma attribute is `null`.

 can anyone tell me whats wrong with my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $globalPost->answered_by)
```

returns a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` ;
`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` has an `increment` function

```
public function increment($column, $amount = 1, array $extra = [])
```

and an `update` function

```
public function update(array $values)
```

so you can try

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $globalPost->answered_by)
        ->increment('karma');
```

or this, this would set karma to 1

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $globalPost->answered_by)
        ->update(['karma'=>1]);
```

if you want use update set karma=karma+1

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $globalPost->answered_by)
        ->update(['karma'=>new Expression('karma + 1')]);
```

Comment: Rof That update function you mentioned in your answer wouldn't it just replace the old karma value with the ``1`` ? I wanna increase the value by 1

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox I just check it in tinker, both worked.Both method return the number of affected rows.

Comment: my default value was null maybe that's why it's was not working.

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox if you really want use update set karma = karma +1 ,you can use `use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $globalPost->answered_by)
        ->update(['karma'=>new Expression('karma + 1')]);`

Comment: I just changed my ``karma`` form ``nullable()`` to ``default(0)`` and used ``increment`` function it all works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#increment-and-decrement you  simply want `increment('karma')` to increment by 1

The second argument may optionally be passed to control the amount by which the column should be incremented or decremented. You do not need to precede the amount with the plus sign either as increment and decrement mean add or subtract respectively